# Is there a way to log an error message when the "Aww snap" page is displayed to an external analytics tool like Logrocket or Datadog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, out-of-memory

My use case is that my webpage suddenly runs out of memory and the Aww Snap error appears. I want to find out a way where I can log the error to some external logger like Datadog or Logrocket so that I can track the error.

I tried looking out for articles but I found that the execution is stopped when the Aww snap error appears.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "*I found that the execution is stopped when the Aww snap error appears.*" - yes. There's nothing you can do with code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you would log that specific error. Is this a React.js app? If so, I would check to see if you have a `useEffect()` that's getting stuck in a never ending loop. I would also use the developer tools to profile your memory usage.

Finally, if you haven't done so already, setting up an error boundary to handle uncaught errors is a good idea. However, I don't know if the error boundary would catch the aww snap.